# How can I get the push id for a firebase database element so as to display it in the listView

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a to-do app, indeed my first firebase app. I have successfully implemented everything with a single text view(todo) under the firebase UID, by creating an array of the push id that returns the push ID when an element is clicked in the List view.

Here was my previous data structure:

[Old data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYaWF.png)

I am stuck with the problem that how can I get the push IDs of elements so that I can reach them and display them in my ListView.

This is the structure that I am trying to fetch :
[New data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4DXI.png)

Here is the code that I use for adding and deleting data in the **old 
Structure**

```
public void Upload(View v) {
    String userId = myRootRef.push().getKey();
    firebaseUniqueID =mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    todoToUpload=todoEditText.getText().toString();
    myRootRef.child(firebaseUniqueID).child(userId).setValue(todoToUpload);
    startActivity(new Intent(AddTodo.this,showTodo.class));
```

Here's the code I use for adding and deleting:

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseDatabase mDataBase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRootRef=mDataBase.getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef;
ListView listView;int pos;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<String> mTodo=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> keysList = new ArrayList<>();

adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.custom_list_layout,R.id.tood,mTodo);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            pos=position;

            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(showTodo.this);
            View mView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_show,null);
            Todo=mView.findViewById(R.id.todo);
            Delete=mView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
            Done=mView.findViewById(R.id.done);
            closer=mView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_close);
            mBuilder.setView(mView);
            final AlertDialog dailog=mBuilder.create();
            myRootRef.child(firebaseUniqueID).child(keysList.get(position)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    todoOpened=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                   Todo.setText(todoOpened);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            Delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(Done.isChecked())
                    {
                        mTodo.remove(pos);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //new code below
                        myRootRef.getRoot().child(firebaseUniqueID).child(keysList.get(pos)).removeValue();
                        keysList.remove(pos);
                        dailog.dismiss();


                    }
                }
            });



 myRootRef.child(firebaseUniqueID)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot firebaseUniqueID : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        keysList.add(firebaseUniqueID.getKey());
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    /*handle errors*/
                }
            });



    userRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String value= dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mTodo.add(value);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Here's the JSON file for the old and new structures

```html
{
  "Z2H2ZkX56fYv3WKxE3a3nCaa8Q63" : {
    "-LNPyZIkX8-uDDGeX-pN" : {
      "Time" : "22:56",
      "Todo" : "play"
    },
    "-LNPze7ppG1L0qFukZO-" : {
      "Priority" : "High",
      "Time" : "22:56",
      "TimeSet" : "09:56",
      "Todo" : "play till the sun goes down"
    },
    "-LNPzhBDDtHv_XSIERX_" : {
      "Priority" : "High",
      "Time" : "22:56",
      "TimeSet" : "09:56",
      "Todo" : "play till the sun goes ddawdawdawdwown"
    }
  }
}
```

```html
{
  "Z2H2ZkX56fYv3WKxE3a3nCaa8Q63" : {
    "-LNQRCZSsYVPqn0tWghZ" : "play in the evening",
    "-LNQRrLliVSxWBHcEIrv" : "I want to shine like a sun"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the key of a `DataSnapshot` by calling its `getKey()` method. So for example:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   todoOpened=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
   String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
   Todo.setText(key + ": "+ todoOpened);
}
```

Comment: Sir, I understand what you said, but my main problems lies in pointing out the path of the database for the datasnapshot like:       mDatabase.child(firebaseUniqueId)...  but now what should I write?

Comment: Is there anyway so that I can get away with it?

Answer (score 0):

you can display list as per your new structure dsplayed in :https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4DXI.png

```
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Messages> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<"Your Class Name">()
                    .setQuery(mMessageThread.child("messages").limitToLast(500), "Your Class Name".class)
                    .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                    .build();
```

use this with firebase adapter.

Then get ToDo text and display it.